# hh:mm import time series

Tags: r, datetime, graph, time-series

This is Excel-made CSV data which is a cyclic 5-minute data export (without dates) (edited, pasted below via dput( )).  The desired outcome with R was to get a line graph for a moving 24 hour window.  The data doesn't have POSIX date-times, only a Time column of hh:mm

The issue is **solved** but I'm pasting here in case it is of use.  I fixed the below code to what I have now that works fine thanks to answers given.  I will now move on to getting the X axis to display hh:mm vertically at hour intervals.

This forum doesn't seem to offer a way I can attach the dput data as a file, is the etiquette to serve posted data in files off remote shares?

```
library(ggplot2)
readings <- read.csv("house_graph.csv", 
             header = TRUE)
png("thing2.png", height = 400, width = 600)

dput(readings, file="readings_data_dump.txt")

readings$Time <- as.POSIXct(readings$Time,format="%H:%M")

ggplot(readings, aes(Time,Total_DRE_power)) + 
geom_line()

dev.off()

structure(list(Time = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,
```

9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 
133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 
144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 
155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 
177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 
188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 
199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 
210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 
221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 
232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 
287L, 288L, 289L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "00:00", "00:05", "00:10", 
"00:15", "00:20", "00:25", "00:30", "00:35", "00:40", "00:45", 
"00:50", "00:55", "01:00", "01:05", "01:10", "01:15", "01:20", 
"01:25", "01:30", "01:35", "01:40", "01:45", "01:50", "01:55", 
"02:00", "02:05", "02:10", "02:15", "02:20", "02:25", "02:30", 
"02:35", "02:40", "02:45", "02:50", "02:55", "03:00", "03:05", 
"03:10", "03:15", "03:20", "03:25", "03:30", "03:35", "03:40", 
"03:45", "03:50", "03:55", "04:00", "04:05", "04:10", "04:15", 
"04:20", "04:25", "04:30", "04:35", "04:40", "04:45", "04:50", 
"04:55", "05:00", "05:05", "05:10", "05:15", "05:20", "05:25", 
"05:30", "05:35", "05:40", "05:45", "05:50", "05:55", "06:00", 
"06:05", "06:10", "06:15", "06:20", "06:25", "06:30", "06:35", 
"06:40", "06:45", "06:50", "06:55", "07:00", "07:05", "07:10", 
"07:15", "07:20", "07:25", "07:30", "07:35", "07:40", "07:45", 
"07:50", "07:55", "08:00", "08:05", "08:10", "08:15", "08:20", 
"08:25", "08:30", "08:35", "08:40", "08:45", "08:50", "08:55", 
"09:00", "09:05", "09:10", "09:15", "09:20", "09:25", "09:30", 
"09:35", "09:40", "09:45", "09:50", "09:55", "10:00", "10:05", 
"10:10", "10:15", "10:20", "10:25", "10:30", "10:35", "10:40", 
"10:45", "10:50", "10:55", "11:00", "11:05", "11:10", "11:15", 
"11:20", "11:25", "11:30", "11:35", "11:40", "11:45", "11:50", 
"11:55", "12:00", "12:05", "12:10", "12:15", "12:20", "12:25", 
"12:30", "12:35", "12:40", "12:45", "12:50", "12:55", "13:00", 
"13:05", "13:10", "13:15", "13:20", "13:25", "13:30", "13:35", 
"13:40", "13:45", "13:50", "13:55", "14:00", "14:05", "14:10", 
"14:15", "14:20", "14:25", "14:30", "14:35", "14:40", "14:45", 
"14:50", "14:55", "15:00", "15:05", "15:10", "15:15", "15:20", 
"15:25", "15:30", "15:35", "15:40", "15:45", "15:50", "15:55", 
"16:00", "16:05", "16:10", "16:15", "16:20", "16:25", "16:30", 
"16:35", "16:40", "16:45", "16:50", "16:55", "17:00", "17:05", 
"17:10", "17:15", "17:20", "17:25", "17:30", "17:35", "17:40", 
"17:45", "17:50", "17:55", "18:00", "18:05", "18:10", "18:15", 
"18:20", "18:25", "18:30", "18:35", "18:40", "18:45", "18:50", 
"18:55", "19:00", "19:05", "19:10", "19:15", "19:20", "19:25", 
"19:30", "19:35", "19:40", "19:45", "19:50", "19:55", "20:00", 
"20:05", "20:10", "20:15", "20:20", "20:25", "20:30", "20:35", 
"20:40", "20:45", "20:50", "20:55", "21:00", "21:05", "21:10", 
"21:15", "21:20", "21:25", "21:30", "21:35", "21:40", "21:45", 
"21:50", "21:55", "22:00", "22:05", "22:10", "22:15", "22:20", 
"22:25", "22:30", "22:35", "22:40", "22:45", "22:50", "22:55", 
"23:00", "23:05", "23:10", "23:15", "23:20", "23:25", "23:30", 
"23:35", "23:40", "23:45", "23:50", "23:55"), class = "factor"), 
    SoC.12 = ...removed ), Total_DRE_power = c(83.33333333, 82.28361872, 
    81.23390411, 80.1841895, 79.13447489, 78.08476027, 77.03504566, 
    76.17962329, 75.32420091, 74.46877854, 73.61335616, 72.75793379, 
    71.90251142, 71.21145358, 70.52039574, 69.8293379, 69.13828006, 
    68.44722222, 67.75616438, 67.16086377, 66.56556317, 65.97026256, 
    65.37496195, 64.77966134, 64.18436073, 63.61495434, 63.04554795, 
    62.47614155, 61.90673516, 61.33732877, 60.76792237, 60.2417618, 
    59.71560122, 59.18944064, 58.66328006, 58.13711948, 57.6109589, 
    57.11048326, 56.61000761, 56.10953196, 55.60905632, 55.10858067, 
    54.60810502, 54.1086758, 53.60924658, 53.10981735, 52.61038813, 
    52.1109589, 51.61152968, 51.1119102, 50.61229072, 50.11267123, 
    49.61305175, 49.11343227, 48.61381279, 48.03445586, 47.45509893, 
    46.87574201, 46.29638508, 45.71702816, 45.13767123, 44.59233257, 
    44.04699391, 43.50165525, 42.95631659, 42.41097793, 41.86563927, 
    41.23061263, 40.595586, 39.96055936, 39.32553272, 38.69050609, 
    38.05547945, 37.20675419, 36.35802892, 35.50930365, 34.66057839, 
    33.81185312, 32.96312785, 31.71276636, 30.46240487, 29.21204338, 
    27.96168189, 26.7113204, 25.4609589, 23.07954718, 20.69813546, 
    18.31672374, 15.93531202, 13.5539003, 11.17248858, 7.932001522, 
    4.69151446, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 
    1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 
    1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 1.451027397, 
    2.451027397, 5.451027397, 9.451027397, 11.16862633, 16.16862633, 
    9.168626332, 5.168626332, 6.168626332, 7.168626332, 7.168626332, 
    10.16862633, 10.16862633, 11.16862633, 11.16862633, 11.16862633, 
    10.16862633, 9.168626332, 8.168626332, 10.16862633, 16.16862633, 
    19.16862633, 16.16862633, 16.16862633, 17.16862633, 14.16862633, 
    17.16862633, 16.16862633, 19.16862633, 21.16862633, 26.16862633, 
    26.36402207, 28.55941781, 32.7386796, 34.25127473, 37.8472032, 
    39.69313166, 41.62239346, 40.63498858, 42.38000381, 39.20835236, 
    55.70336758, 120.5317161, 160.6100647, 176.4384132, 178.5799467, 
    222.0548135, 258.3630137, 264.6712139, 194.3127473, 198.9542808, 
    281.2783486, 298.9357496, 313.0098174, 363.1672184, 377.4079528, 
    322.6666667, 329.6666667, 342.6666667, 316.6666667, 320.6666667, 
    332.6666667, 358.6666667, 381.6666667, 267.6666667, 299.6666667, 
    336.6666667, 350.6666667, 381.6666667, 363.6666667, 340.6666667, 
    337.6666667, 350.6666667, 259.6666667, 245.6666667, 235.6666667, 
    310.6666667, 299.6666667, 262.6666667, 244.6666667, 234.6666667, 
    232.6666667, 227.6666667, 224.6666667, 225.6666667, 224.6666667, 
    220.6666667, 231.6666667, 230.6666667, 227.6666667, 230.6666667, 
    226.6666667, 216.6666667, 211.0757801, 201.0682268, 193.3106735, 
    190.0531202, 180.7122336, 182.7880137, 180.2023212, 176.6166286, 
    172.9476027, 170.1952435, 161.4428843, 158.1905251, 148.3640411, 
    140.0375571, 138.3777397, 134.9679224, 127.6414384, 122.0649543, 
    115.1025685, 107.973516, 101.6777968, 94.29874429, 86.75302511, 
    81.04063927, 75.56607686, 70.09151446, 64.61695205, 59.14238965, 
    53.66782725, 48.19326484, 43.56236682, 38.9314688, 34.30057078, 
    29.66967275, 25.03877473, 20.40787671, 15.931621, 11.4553653, 
    6.979109589, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 
    2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 
    2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 
    2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 
    2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 
    2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 
    2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 2.502853881, 0.178158295, 
    0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 
    0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 
    0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 0.178158295, 
    0.178158295, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Future_Demand = c(10.07726027, 10.07726027, 
    10.07726027, 10.07726027, 10.07726027, 10.07726027, 8.212054795, 
    8.212054795, 8.212054795, 8.212054795, 8.212054795, 8.212054795, 
    6.634155251, 6.634155251, 6.634155251, 6.634155251, 6.634155251, 
    6.634155251, 5.714885845, 5.714885845, 5.714885845, 5.714885845, 
    5.714885845, 5.714885845, 5.46630137, 5.46630137, 5.46630137, 
    5.46630137, 5.46630137, 5.46630137, 5.051141553, 5.051141553, 
    5.051141553, 5.051141553, 5.051141553, 5.051141553, 4.80456621, 
    4.80456621, 4.80456621, 4.80456621, 4.80456621, 4.80456621, 
    4.794520548, 4.794520548, 4.794520548, 4.794520548, 4.794520548, 
    4.794520548, 4.796347032, 4.796347032, 4.796347032, 4.796347032, 
    4.796347032, 4.796347032, 5.561826484, 5.561826484, 5.561826484, 
    5.561826484, 5.561826484, 5.561826484, 5.235251142, 5.235251142, 
    5.235251142, 5.235251142, 5.235251142, 5.235251142, 6.096255708, 
    6.096255708, 6.096255708, 6.096255708, 6.096255708, 6.096255708, 
    8.147762557, 8.147762557, 8.147762557, 8.147762557, 8.147762557, 
    8.147762557, 12.00347032, 12.00347032, 12.00347032, 12.00347032, 
    12.00347032, 12.00347032, 22.86155251, 22.86155251, 22.86155251, 
    22.86155251, 22.86155251, 22.86155251, 31.1086758, 31.1086758, 
    31.1086758, 31.1086758, 31.1086758, 31.1086758, 29.61442922, 
    29.61442922, 29.61442922, 29.61442922, 29.61442922, 29.61442922, 
    26.41278539, 26.41278539, 26.41278539, 26.41278539, 26.41278539, 
    26.41278539, 18.71105023, 18.71105023, 18.71105023, 18.71105023, 
    18.71105023, 18.71105023, 17.49260274, 17.49260274, 17.49260274, 
    17.49260274, 17.49260274, 17.49260274, 17.63050228, 17.63050228, 
    17.63050228, 17.63050228, 17.63050228, 17.63050228, 17.97022831, 
    17.97022831, 17.97022831, 17.97022831, 17.97022831, 17.97022831, 
    18.92420091, 18.92420091, 18.92420091, 18.92420091, 18.92420091, 
    18.92420091, 20.67908676, 20.67908676, 20.67908676, 20.67908676, 
    20.67908676, 20.67908676, 21.64785388, 21.64785388, 21.64785388, 
    21.64785388, 21.64785388, 21.64785388, 23.44127854, 23.44127854, 
    23.44127854, 23.44127854, 23.44127854, 23.44127854, 24.88894977, 
    24.88894977, 24.88894977, 24.88894977, 24.88894977, 24.88894977, 
    26.83525114, 26.83525114, 26.83525114, 26.83525114, 26.83525114, 
    26.83525114, 28.15817352, 28.15817352, 28.15817352, 28.15817352, 
    28.15817352, 28.15817352, 30.21150685, 30.21150685, 30.21150685, 
    30.21150685, 30.21150685, 30.21150685, 34.36584475, 34.36584475, 
    34.36584475, 34.36584475, 34.36584475, 34.36584475, 36.85954338, 
    36.85954338, 36.85954338, 36.85954338, 36.85954338, 36.85954338, 
    39.75561644, 39.75561644, 39.75561644, 39.75561644, 39.75561644, 
    39.75561644, 45.67251142, 45.67251142, 45.67251142, 45.67251142, 
    45.67251142, 45.67251142, 46.4226484, 46.4226484, 46.4226484, 
    46.4226484, 46.4226484, 46.4226484, 51.93424658, 51.93424658, 
    51.93424658, 51.93424658, 51.93424658, 51.93424658, 54.83890411, 
    54.83890411, 54.83890411, 54.83890411, 54.83890411, 54.83890411, 
    52.55579909, 52.55579909, 52.55579909, 52.55579909, 52.55579909, 
    52.55579909, 44.456621, 44.456621, 44.456621, 44.456621, 
    44.456621, 44.456621, 42.97205479, 42.97205479, 42.97205479, 
    42.97205479, 42.97205479, 42.97205479, 42.00913242, 42.00913242, 
    42.00913242, 42.00913242, 42.00913242, 42.00913242, 41.97844749, 
    41.97844749, 41.97844749, 41.97844749, 41.97844749, 41.97844749, 
    40.34520548, 40.34520548, 40.34520548, 40.34520548, 40.34520548, 
    40.34520548, 35.15506849, 35.15506849, 35.15506849, 35.15506849, 
    35.15506849, 35.15506849, 29.18045662, 29.18045662, 29.18045662, 
    29.18045662, 29.18045662, 29.18045662, 22.31707763, 22.31707763, 
    22.31707763, 22.31707763, 22.31707763, 22.31707763, 18.40547945, 
    18.40547945, 18.40547945, 18.40547945, 18.40547945, 18.40547945, 
    13.71598174, 13.71598174, 13.71598174, 13.71598174, 13.71598174, 
    13.71598174, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),  ....removed... , .Names = c("Time", 
"SoC.12", "SoC..Wh.", "Battery..Wh.", "Grid..Wh.", "Solar..Wh.", 
"Temp...C..", "Current_Demand", "Total_DRE_power", "Future_Demand", 
"Current_Demand_plot", "Future_Demand_plot", "grid1", "grid2", 
"grid3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -304L))

Comment: could You please post Your data using `dput()`

Comment: If you supply the variables as strings to `aes` you have to use `aes_string()`. To make `geom_line()` work you have to convert `Time` to a POSIX or a number.

Comment: you can use `readings$Time <- as.POSIXct(readings$Time,format="%H:%M")` on your data to plot your times relative to today. ggplot should then plot `Time` correctly.

Comment: @MichaelBird this has worked, thank you.